# ksh: get last element of an array - command not found

Tags: shell, ksh

In my script, one of the function returns an array value and I wanted to get its last value and 'cd' into that directory

function name is '**folders**' which returns an array holding the values say - **4.5.0 6.0 2.3.1**

If I use- `cd $(folders[-1])` , I'm facing the following error - `my_script.sh: line 350: folders[-1]: command not found`

On using - `cd ${folders[-1]}` , I'm getting - `my_script.sh: line 350: folders: bad array subscript`

What am I missing here, thanks

Comment: Do you use bash or ksh?

Comment: @Cyrus : its in ksh

Comment: `Make that "${a[@]: -1}" and it will work (besides bash and zsh) also in ksh` https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198787/is-there-a-way-of-reading-the-last-element-of-an-array-with-bash

Comment: @error404 That evaluates to the entire array for me.

Comment: Which **specific** version of ksh? mksh, pdksh, ksh88 and ksh93 (to pick four at random) are almost completely different shells, and the last of that list is the only one someone should voluntarily use and expect to have a reasonable feature set.

Comment: `$(...)` always runs `...` as a command, btw, so "command not found" is completely normal/expected there. I'd almost edit that attempt out of the question to focus on `${...}`, which at least *is* a parameter expansion and not a command substitution.

Comment: ...waitaminute, "returns"? Functions can't meaningfully return arrays at all. You're going to need to show us your code, because you're almost certainly not doing what you think you're doing. Either you're *really* emitting a string on stdout, or you're setting an array as a side effect, or you're doing something completely different... either way, we'd need to actually see the function.

Answer (score 2):

`${foo[-1]}` works on my ksh. But if it doesn't for you, maybe:

```
#!/bin/ksh93
foo=(1 2 3)
echo "${foo[-1]}" # Should print 3
echo "${foo[${#foo[@]} - 1]}" # Should also print 3
```

`${#foo[@]}` returns the number of elements in the array variable, so you just subtract one from that to get the last element.

Comment: I tried `${foo[-1]}` on my function's output, still the same error.
`bad array subscript`

Comment: @Goku How is your function returning an array and how are you capturing that value?

Comment: (You should update your question to include this instead of trying to put code in a comment)